# Why are some contacts shown several times?

Tags: contacts

Some of my contacts are on SIM card and some are on phone. I want to keep all at one place.  If I transfer them from SIM card to phone, am I going to have duplicate contacts or it is smart enough to figure out?

If I select the option "all contacts" then one contact is shown several time in the list, like one for wiber, waze, whatapps etc. Please help me to manage my contacts.

Answer (score 1):

1. if your contacts are shown from different accounts (google & non-google accounts), just disable one of the accounts to hide multiple contacts.
2. If you have duplicate contacts on your Google account, simply go to Google Contacts website via desktop, and choose option "merge (or delete, I can't remember) multiple contacts". Sync your phone contacts and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to my android too.

Whenever you restore your contacts over GOOGLE, it gives you a copy of the last contacts you uploaded to GOOGLE, And when you use your SD CARD to have your contacts by default, it will duplicate said contacts whenever you restore, and then when you restore over GOOGLE again, it will copy it again, and again, and again...

Just delete the contacts that are duplicated, and disable google from restoring you contacts in the settings. It should stop.

Answer (score 0):

Please open Contacts application. In menu option select "contacts to display". Option list will open . Select customise . List of accounts will open . Pick which accounts you want . Problem solved. Hole you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

You have to select which contacts you want to display at the given options, since you are displaying all of them and their associated accounts, for example WhatsApp/Viber etc.

Answer (score 0):

The app [Simpler Caller ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simpler.contacts) can merge duplicate contacts. To do that, open the app → go to Tools → Duplicates, and then press Merge.